# How route traffic in AWS NLB to just 2 instances out of 4 unless they are down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am setting up an DR environment and wanted to see how can I route my network traffic to just 2 specific instances out of 4 total instances and only route the traffic to other 2 if the primary 2 are down.

--Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not how NLB or other LBs work. They distribute traffic equally **among all targets** in a TG. You can't have "primary" targets.

Instead you put your all targets in an autoscaling group (ASG) and setup its [health check to NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/healthcheck.html). This way ASG can **automatically detect** in-healthy targets, and replace them when needed.

However, if you had two NLBs, you could setup **failover**'s using [DNS failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html) or CloudFront's [origin failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html).